# How to make a column for each string word in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
`id` `text`
1     Hello world how are you
2     Hello people I am fine
3     Good Morning
4     Good Evening
```

I want to take each word and make different columns for them. They will contain only two values 1 or 0 (1 means the word is present in the text, 0 means nope)

Expected output:

```
`id` `text`                   Hello  world how are you people I am fine Good Morning Evening
1     Hello world how are you   1      1    1   1   1    1    1  1   1    1      1      1
2     Hello people I am fine    1      0    0   0   0    1    1  1   1    0      0      0
3     Good Morning              0      0    0   0   0    0    0  0   0    1      1      0
4     Good Evening              0      0    0   0   0    0    0  0   0    1      0      1
```

Comment: Need `df.join(df.text.str.get_dummies(' '))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df.join(df.text.str.get_dummies(sep=' '))
```

Comment: I have list more repeatead dupes.

Comment: @Wen-Ben - hmmm, idea - I can get my dupe lists to my profile.

Comment: I think it better list most of your famous answers in your file, since your answers alway nice and succinct and cover most of the common questions  :-)

Comment: I asked like 5-6 quesitons related to pandas and you always answer. Is stackoverflow your full time job? If no, then don't you get bored? Do u even do something other than stackoverflow? ::P Just curious hehe, u r doing great job, appreciate it a lot man..seriously

Comment: @johndoe - no, it is my hobby. I have advantage I have a lot of time, so I can answering daily.

Comment: @jezrael great job. This will help the community. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - I rather filter a bit longer list ;)

Comment: @jezrael ha ha. i know. :D but still it will help users like me who is still fresh in marking dupes

Comment: @jezrael That is great

Answer (score 4):

This is `get_dummies`

```
pd.concat([df,df.text.str.get_dummies(' ')],axis=1)
```

Comment: How do I concat those two dataframes?

Comment: `pd.concat([df,df.text.str.get_dummies(' ')],axis=)` @johndoe

Comment: @Wen-Ben Hi Wen, I had some questions on my data science aspirations(on numpy), where can I email/connect you?

Comment: @anky_91 currently I do not have a email for stack but you can always ping me here or even we can creat a chat room:-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben That will be great. Actually I had targetted to learn pandas first and now that I have crossed 10K, i think i am ready to go for the next 10 K on numpy(though there are some things on pandas yet to practise). Just to make myself ready for the algos in scikit learn. I have already completed some basics in scikitlearn. but while doing it, i felt getting a grip in numpy and pandas is a must before ML what do you suggest. :)

Comment: @anky_91 for `numpy` if you would like to learn it in stack , I will recommended check some high vote answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar, Also about to mentioned , both numpy and scipy are important for ML

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks a lot. :)